# Known HDD user password not working on new Bios

Tags: hard-drive, bios, external-hard-drive, passwords

I have an ASUS-K75VM that's not working again. I have tried to use its HDD on different laptops, but in vain so far because ***the correct password*** is not working/accepted. **My 500 G data at risk.**
The **HDD user password** which I set is not accepted on other laptops. It prompts to enter the **HDD user password** on start. I had set the password in the Bios on the ASUS and had been using it along with the Bios password before it crashed. It's not BitLocker.

**What to do, please ?**

**INFO:** *I tried Master Passwords, I connected the HDD to another PC using a caddy (disk box) but couldn't access its data.*

Comment: Most likely it's because the old BIOS hashed / padded your input before passing the password to the disk controller, and the new BIOS (or software) either pass your input as-is or "preprocessed" it in a different way when you try to unlock; or the other way round. (Assuming you set it via BIOS setting instead of with e.g. hdparm.) It happens quite often AFAIR.

Comment: Also not all "caddy" support ATA security feature set very well, FWIW.

Comment: @TomYan Your short comments give more insight than the answer (IMO low quality answer) that used to be here. The answer is now deleted and you cannot see it. I'm writing this to give a clue to the author of the answer about what quality I expected from his answer.

Comment: If it is indeed an ATA password (AKA Bios Disk Password) it is most likely not transferable to another computer. You could be lucky if you find a replacement motherboard (or a very similar one, using a nearly identical bios) from the same manufacturer. Even then your chances are slim. Caddy's, USB enclosures will NEVER work because the BIOS must see the disk attached to a SATA port. (And in most cases it has to be the 1st SATA port.)

Comment: A caddy could work if it is internally directly connected to a SATA port on the motherboard. It depends on the type of caddy and the exact electronics inside.

Comment: @TomYan You have identified the problem well, I set it via the Bios, now remains the solution I can exploit to help me regain access to my school stuff on the disk, it has been driving me crazy for some time now... I do not know what to do.

Comment: @Tonny That's my misfortune currently.... I'm completely overwhelmed...

Comment: You can try Victoria for Windows, hook up drive via USB, Service > Security Operations. Enter password and click Unlock.

Comment: I've seen some HDD forum posts that keep sort of a knowledge base of how different MB/BIOS would treat the password input. But I suppose it takes luck and Google-fu to find a match. (Or, just try different common padding as suggested / implied in @JoepvanSteen 's answer.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try Victoria for Windows, hook up drive via USB. Note that you don't mention the hard drive brand / model. If it is a desktop drive you need USB adapter / enclosure with power adapter.

1. Select drive
2. Click Service
3. Select Security Operations
4. Enter password
5. Click Unlock drive

[image]

https://hdd.by/victoria/ - Use Google translate to navigate the website.

Also note:

[Your new PC may use different filler character to make certain the  password is 32 characters long than original PC.](https://hdd.by/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82/) - (click me for more info)

Password is padded to 32 characters. Victoria will pad with zeros, you can try manually enter password and pad with spaces so password + spaces = 32 characters length. The pad character may depend on device it was originally in at the time the password was set.

Comment: Huh? The tool I suggest can help unlock an ATA locked hard drive. This has zero to do with Veracrypt.

Comment: Sorry. Misread. :-)

Comment: @JoepvanSteen Thanks, I will try it and get back to you. My HDD is a seagate drive Model Number: ST1000LM024.